# Undefined al recorrer un array en json en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, dom

Hola estoy recorriendo un array en javascript, y me dice undefined, el caso es que me lo recorre, pero no muestra los datos, donde estaría el error ? Gracias de antemano...!

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute("id", "div1");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.setAttribute("id", "div2");
var div3 = document.createElement("div");
div3.setAttribute("id", "resultado");

document.body.appendChild(div1);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div3);

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let data = [];

    let url1 = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

    xhttp.open('GET',url1,true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(datos);

            let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');
            resultado.innerHTML = '';

            for(let item in datos){
              [item.first_name,item.last_name,item.avatar];

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var p0 = document.createElement('p');
                var p1 = document.createElement('p');
                var p2 = document.createElement('p');
                
                var hr = document.createElement('hr');

                p0.innerHTML = item.first_name;
                p1.innerHTML = item.last_name;
                p2.innerHTML = item.avatar

                div.appendChild(hr);
                div.appendChild(p0).appendChild(p1);
                
                div.appendChild(p2);

                console.log(item);
                resultado.appendChild(div);
            }

        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está que recorres todo el arreglo y lo que buscas es recorrer la parte `data` para extraer los datos de los usuarios

```js
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.setAttribute("id", "div1");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div2.setAttribute("id", "div2");
var div3 = document.createElement("div");
div3.setAttribute("id", "resultado");

document.body.appendChild(div1);
document.body.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div3);

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    let data = [];

    let url1 = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

    xhttp.open('GET',url1,true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            // aquí solo agregué ['data']
            console.log(datos['data']);

            let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');
            resultado.innerHTML = '';
            
            //len variable donde guardo tamaño del array datos['data'] 
            len = datos['data'].length;
            //cambié a un for tradicional
            for(let i =0 ; i<len ; i++){
              //igualo la variable item a la correspondiente iteración 
              let item = datos['data'][i];
              [item.first_name,item.last_name,item.avatar];

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var p0 = document.createElement('p');
                var p1 = document.createElement('p');
                var p2 = document.createElement('p');
                
                var hr = document.createElement('hr');

                p0.innerHTML = item.first_name;
                p1.innerHTML = item.last_name;
                p2.innerHTML = item.avatar

                div.appendChild(hr);
                div.appendChild(p0).appendChild(p1);
                
                div.appendChild(p2);

                console.log(item.first_name);
                resultado.appendChild(div);
            }

        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta @alejandro00, era lo que estaba buscando, un saludo !

Comment: listo borrado @alejandro00 ya hice la pregunta de nuevo un saludo !